# Java: way to completely disable any Swing unwanted beeps?

Tags: java, swing, beep

I am working on a fairly complex Java application using Swing.

On some occasions there are unwanted beeps without any user intervention. No crash, application keeps working fine, I'm respecting the EDT rules etc.

Yet in some cases a beep can be heard: I may be doing something silly triggering that beep but in any case it s not a user action for it can happen upon importing data, when the user is away.

Is it possible, for a Java application that should never ever emit any sound to configure it, say by setting a property for the whole application that says: "dont' ever emit a beep"?

I ve been Googling for that issue and I ve found message by people having the same issue but no answer: all I found was some hack saying that there was a known issue with JEditorPane and that using a `putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", Boolean.TRUE)` was helpful to make unwanted beeps happen less often.  Yet information is very scarce on the subject.

It s a real issue because the application is used in an environment where the sound is needed on the computer, but this Java application emitting noise is unacceptable.

Comment: What are you doing when you receive a "beep" in the application?  That might help better focus the answers.  (Also, the OS may be making the beeps depending on the situation.)

Comment: @Jason: Financial data are imported in real-time and the UI (a complex UI) is updated but the users ain't doing anything.  I d really like to know if there s a way to disable, application-wide, sound for a Java application which we know for a fact should never emit any sound. I'm pretty sure it s a Java issue because there isn t a single other app emitting unwanted beeps.  Once again, there s a know issue concerning JEditorPane and a setProperty hack. This is related to Swing, not to the OS, I m pretty sure.

Comment: @mre: great link.  I understand that but still, it would be great to have a way to specify "this application should never emit any sound".

Comment: @mre: make this an answer, I ll accept it, it looks like exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is discussed on the Java Forum:

```
// Write a custom toolkit
public class MyToolkit extends sun.awt.windows.WToolkit 
{
  public void beep() {
  }
}

// Set this property
System.setProperty("awt.toolkit", "MyPackage.MyToolkit");
```

`NOTE:` The use of this workaround is discouraged. You should still try to find the root of the problem.

---

**Edit:** Removed a link, since the thread on Java Forum is now offline.

Comment: Could you print a stack trace from the beep() to find the source of the problem?  e.g. `(new Exception()).printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0):

In Swing you need to override the `LookAndFeel` as follows:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel() {

  @Override
  public void provideErrorFeedback(Component component) {

    // Your beep decision goes here

    // You want error feedback 
    super.provideErrorFeedback(component);

  }
});
```

Typically your beep decision would reference some kind of external configuration/preferences flag for your application.