# How to disable sound when I press ALT+ ENTER in javafx.scene.control.TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

```
 val textArea = new TextArea(text) {
      addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, (event: KeyEvent) => {
        if (event.getEventType == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && event.getCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
          event.consume()
          if (event.isAltDown)
            insertText(getCaretPosition,"\n")
        }
      })
    }
```

How to disable sound when I press ALT+ ENTER in javafx.scene.control.TextArea?

Comment: Which sound do you want to disable? Do you have a media player instance somewhere in your application?

Comment: The sound is the same as when you press the ALT+ENTER in Google Chrome or calc.exe

Comment: bully: "Do you have a media player instance somewhere in your application?". No, I don't.

Comment: I think what you're asking for is muting the system sounds. At least for the browser, I'm quite sure there is no way to turn off the sounds for the whole browser instance, or to be a little bit more general: the container you're running your FX application in. It wouldn't make sense to me anyway. 
Though [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266549/java-way-to-completely-disable-any-swing-unwanted-beeps) is for Swing, maybe this is helpful for you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method that will mute all current sounds.

```
sound.setVolume(0); (For audioclip)
mediaPlayer.setMute(true); (For MediaPlayer)
```

Hope this helps.