# How to remove the sound played when focus is transferred to an uneditable JTextComponent

Tags: java, jtextfield, jtextpane, toolkit

How can I get rid of the sound when I give focus to an uneditable JTextField or JTextPane?

Whenever I transfer focus to a JTextPane which is uneditable and hit Enter, a sound plays which is equals to the "beep" of the Toolkit class:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.beet();
```

How can I make it play no sound?

Comment: Please add some short code example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to try the idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13427565/4112645), quoted:

The idea is to get the beep action for the text field and disabling it.

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
Action action;
action = field.getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.beepAction);
action.setEnabled(false);
```

If that does not work, you can try to add a `KeyListener`, that would consume the `KeyEvent` that causes the beep.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
      // will consume the event and stop it from processing normally
      e.consume();
    }        
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work this is what i put in my code:
     Action action;

     action = getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.beepAction);

     action.setEnabled(false);

Comment: thanks for the update, I have added another suggestion you could try for stopping the beep.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `beep` method from the `Toolkit` class:

```
public class MuteToolkit extends Toolkit {
    public void beep() {
        //do nothing
    }
    // [...] other methods
}
```

Then, set this class as the default toolkit:

```
System.setProperty("awt.toolkit", "package.MuteToolkit");
```

But may be not the best option, considering it disables all beeps.

Comment: if I do that... I have to make a implementation of all methods and each one throw new UnsupportedOperationException, so in this method "public Image createImage(ImageProducer producer)" i can't left in blank

Comment: You can also extends the basic implementation of Toolkit, the same returned from `getDefaultToolkit` method.

Comment: I cant because these methods are protected... protected abstract DesktopPeer createDesktopPeer(Desktop target)
      throws HeadlessException; so DefaultToolkit don't have any of these