# Java: How to disable JSpinner beeping

Tags: java, input, jspinner, beep

When invalid input is entered into the JSpinner, a beep is played, and I can't figure out how to disable it.

I'm using a number spinner with invalid input not being allowed to be typed in, like so:

```
public class SpinnerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 100, 1));


        //disable invalid input from being typed into spinner
        JFormattedTextField textField = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
        ((NumberFormatter) textField.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid(false);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(spinner);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: So I figured out how to do this. Honestly, its a complete hack-job and shouldn't be done. Better yet, why would you want to disable that? It really seems like you need a better system altogether.

Comment: @Obicere Out of curiosity, how did you do it? I've tried several methods, but the only one that worked for me was the one posted below, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if there is a better way, but one way is to make a custom look and feel that disables beeping altogether. This achieves the desired effect, but also disables beeping for the entire program, not just the spinner.

```
public class SpinnerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 0, 100, 1));


        //disable invalid input from being typed into spinner
        JFormattedTextField textField = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
        ((NumberFormatter) textField.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid(false);

        /**
         * Change look and field
         */
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MyLookAndFeel());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(spinner);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }

    /**
     * Create Look and Feel without beeps
     */
    public static class MyLookAndFeel extends NimbusLookAndFeel {
        @Override
        public void provideErrorFeedback(Component component) {
            //super.provideErrorFeedback(component);
        }
    }
}
```

Based off an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266549/java-way-to-completely-disable-any-swing-unwanted-beeps).